# How to loop through each column with a different condition in a pandas dataframe - shared x axis plot

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop

Please excuse any obvious errors from a new, low confidence pandas user.

**I have a dataframe with columns that require to be cleaned individually as have different number of valid entries. My aim is to resample the data per day, month and year and plot daily, monthly and yearly data (as timeseries) for each of the columns. I want a shared x axis, multiple y axis plot for each of the columns, showing daily, monthly and yearly series.**

If I run the drona() and resample function on the entire dataframe, it is generating an empty dataframe for each resample operation. My guess is that it is dropping all the rows with even one column of NaN.

So, I thought of filtering out each column in a loop and creating sub dataframes with one column filtered at a time. In the end, I could do a shared x axis plot for each of the smaller frames generated.

Is there a better way to meet my objectives?

This is my dataframe:

```
                     col1   col2  col3  col4  col5
date                                              
2015-01-03 00:00:00  None    32    42    None     3
2015-01-03 01:00:00    45    34    34     78     1.5
2015-01-03 02:00:00  None  53.5    NaN   None    1.5
```

This is a part of my code for looping over columns and applying conditions:

```
for i in df.columns:
    print (i)
    df.[i]= pd.to_numeric(df.i,errors='coerce' )
    df=df[df['i'].notna()]
    df = df[df['i'] >= 0]
    df=df.filter (items = [i])
    #Resampling :
    df_hour = df['i'].resample('h').apply(lambda x: x.mean() if x.count()>1 else np.nan)
    df_hour_fix = df_hour[df_hour != np.nan]
    print (df_hour_fix)
```

Running it, this error crops up:
**'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'**

Comment: You should provide a sample of the DataFrame and say what kind of cleanup needs to be done to each column. In this case, looping through the columns may not be necessary. Also, did you try the code you provided? What error or how the output from it differs from the desired output?

Comment: I have made changes; can you check now? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the line `df.i`. You can access columns as attributes in `dataframe` but with `df.i` you are trying to access the attribute `i` and not the column whose value is given by value of the variable `i`. Which is what the error is saying.

Comment: as mentioned by @DOOM that error will be fixed by replacing df.i by df[i]. Also, some steps in your loop don't make sense to me. Would you mind explaining what is that you are trying to accomplish on each one of them? Also, provide a desired output. What should the final dataframe look like?

Comment: Thank you @teoeme139 and DOOM. I have rephrased my problem.Maybe it is more explicit now.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps and if it can lead you the correct way. I used a different df to have more data to work with

```
                     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
2000-01-01 00:00:00   NaN     0     0   NaN     0
2000-01-01 01:00:00   3.0     1     1   NaN     1
2000-01-01 02:00:00   4.0     2     2   NaN     2
2000-01-01 03:00:00   5.0     3     3   NaN     3
2000-01-01 04:00:00   NaN     4     4   NaN     4
2000-01-01 05:00:00   2.0     5     5   NaN     5
2000-01-01 06:00:00   9.0     6     6   NaN     6
2000-01-01 07:00:00   NaN     7     7   NaN     7
2000-01-01 08:00:00   NaN     8     8   NaN     8
```

Avoid the loop. I'd clean up the df by doing:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df = df.mask(df<0)
```

Lastly, resample the df every 2 hours and calculate the mean. The default for the mean method is to ignore NaN. So you can safely execute it with NaNs in your df.

```
df_hour = df.resample('2H').mean()

                     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
2000-01-01 00:00:00   3.0   0.5   0.5   NaN   0.5
2000-01-01 02:00:00   4.5   2.5   2.5   NaN   2.5
2000-01-01 04:00:00   2.0   4.5   4.5   NaN   4.5
2000-01-01 06:00:00   9.0   6.5   6.5   NaN   6.5
2000-01-01 08:00:00   NaN   8.0   8.0   NaN   8.0
```

Comment: Thanks @teoeme139. I was using your approach all this while but it does not give me required results. I have made changes to my dataframe that makes it more descriptive of my problem. Could you suggest a solution in such a case?

Comment: I made a few changes. Let me know if it improves